# PHP Create table does nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I can't create a table from PHP code. Every time I check in phpMyAdmin, I can see the database but not the table. I've tried different solutions but no one worked.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbprova');

mysqli_query($con, "CREATE TABLE Employees 
(employee_id INT, first_name VARCHAR(50), last_name  VARCHAR(50)");
```

Comment: try check for error like in the example https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: You have a typo. Enable error checking and you will see the error similar to "Syntax error near". Hint: count your brackets

Comment: there is missing a parentheses at the end of the command